# Creating a fixed sidebar alongside a centered Bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'd like to create a fixed sidebar that exists **outside** my centered Bootstrap Grid. The challenge I face when attempting to do this is determining what additional styles to apply/overwrite to my `.container` so that it doesn't overlap my sidebar when the screen is resized.

For starters I'm only using the grid portion of the css framework so the `.container`, `.row` and `.col-md-12` is code pulled from the `bootstrap.css` file itself and is not custom. Also keep in mind I'm using **Bootstrap 3**, so please, no suggestions for a fluid grid solution for Bootstrap 2 that is often asked about in previous threads.

**HTML**

```
<div id="left-nav"></div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nunc dictum at.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#left-nav {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html

Comment: It appears so. Thank you so much.

Comment: Above link isn't working anymore.

Comment: @EjazKarim fixed link: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/

Comment: @EjazKarim I have copied out the HTML and CSS [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20558082/1890236)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

[As drew_w said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557912/creating-a-fixed-sidebar-alongside-a-centered-bootstrap-3-grid#comment30746067_20557912), you can find a [good example here](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Next link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- content of page -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #CCC;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {

    #wrapper {
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
      left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.active {
      position: relative;
      left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
      left: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }

}
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eggleton/24sh7y11/)**</kbd>

Comment: How would one change the code to make it stick to the right instead?

Comment: @masb I would suggest trying to change all the references of `padding-left`, `margin-left` and `left`, to `padding-right`, `margin-right` and `right` respectively

Comment: What I really like about this is it isn't bloated with markup and css. So I can easily review the code and understand it and then make any necessary changes.

Comment: I like this, but it seems that mine always loads the page in the toggled (hidden sidebar state).  I used code straight from the example in the link.  I wonder why it would be different.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jordan yep, resize your screen. the `@media` declaration means that it will show/hide depending on the screen size. OP used `col-md-12` in their question which is what I used in my example. I have added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eggleton/24sh7y11/) to the question for more info.

Comment: This is great! The only tweak I'd like to see is have a full-width navbar at the top. Then the sidebar would only start BELOW the top navbar...

Comment: This is not a good solution, container has widths in pixels and by shifting it through the left-padding that means you will get scrollbars when resizing.