# How to create a non-fixed sidebar (Bootstrap grid)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can only find solutions for fixed sidebars (e.g. [Creating a fixed sidebar alongside a centered Bootstrap 3 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557912/creating-a-fixed-sidebar-alongside-a-centered-bootstrap-3-grid)), but not for **non-fixed** ones, i.e. a sidebar that scrolls down with the content.

I am using a bootstrap grid (Bootstrap 4):

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top">...</nav>
<!--content-->
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <img src=https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
```

I need a sidebar to the left of this content, but under my top navigation bar. How do I do this?

(the number of rows I need is undefined. They will later be generated by a php loop, so I don't think I can put the sidebar in the grid system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the content in a wrapper, put another DIV before that, wrap a row around them and apply the usual classes to divide the page width:

```html
<nav class="navbar sticky-top">...</nav>
<!--content-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
      SIDEBAR
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x130">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        some other content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZedxM

Comment: I tried that, but it seems like the formatting breaks this way. E.g. if you insert the  `col-md-3 ` and  `img ` in the second  `div<class="row"> ` in your codepen, the images are weirdly placed. Is that because a  `row ` is used within a  `row `?

Comment: You just have to be careful to close all DIVs properly - look at the codepen now, i added a second row in the right container....